# How do you set the background colour of a Spark IconItemRenderer?

Tags: android, flex4, flash-builder

I'm almost embarrassed to ask this but I simply cannot get my head around it!

I have the following list:

```
    <s:List id="list" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0"
        change="navigator.pushView(EmployeeDetails, list.selectedItem)" dataProvider="{data}" borderVisible="true" borderColor="0x000000" >
    <s:itemRenderer>
        <fx:Component>
                <s:IconItemRenderer label="{data.firstName} {data.lastName}" messageField="title" opaqueBackground="0x000000"/>
        </fx:Component>
    </s:itemRenderer>
</s:List>
```

How on earth do you get the background colour of the IconItemRenderer or itemRenderer to display? Everything I've tried results in a boring white background for each list item.

Regards, Daniel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to solve this by using "alternatingItemColors" with only one colour!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, I think you have to set the List **autoDrawBackground** property of the List to false.

Comment: Unfortunately the List doesn't have an autoDrawBackground property

Comment: My mistake, you may have to look for this property on your itemRenderer directly, as shown here : 
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS77c1dbb1bd80d38313b7ce1c129eb7d5e04-8000.html

Comment: itemRenderer doesn't have an autoDrawBackground property. ItemRenderer does.